# Qual a diferença nas sintaxe ptr = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int)) e ptr = malloc (sizeof(int))?

Tags: c, memória, alocação, malloc

Estou com uma duvida sobre alocação dinâmica em C.
No momento de alocar a memoria já vi esses dois tipos de sintaxe:

```
ptr = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int));
ptr = malloc (sizeof(int));
```

Porém não sei qual a diferença no uso entre elas. Cada site parece falar uma coisa diferente. Alguém poderia me explicar a diferença?

Comment: Depende da versão do C

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ambas as instruções fazem o mesmo, e o resultado final é o mesmo, diferindo apenas em pormenores de escrita e portabilidade.

Relembro que a função [`malloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) devolve um `void*`, ou seja um ponteiro de tipo genérico, e não o poderá utilizar diretamente sem que ele seja primeiro convertido para o tipo que pretende.

### Com cast

```
ptr = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int));
```

Neste caso converte explicitamente o `void*` para `int*`. Isto fará com o que o código seja portável para alguns compiladores muito antigos ou para c++, ainda que em c++ tenha formas melhores de alocar memória que não o [`malloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/).

### Sem cast

```
ptr = malloc (sizeof(int));
```

Aqui o `void*` é automaticamente promovido para o tipo de ponteiro que tem à esquerda, o de `ptr`. Significa que se `ptr` for do tipo `int*`:

```
int *ptr = malloc (sizeof(int));
```

O `void*` é convertido para `int*` pelo compilador. Isto dá-lhe mais flexibilidade pois se tiver de mudar o tipo de `ptr` é menos um local onde tem de mudar coisas. Consegue dar ainda mais um passo nesta direção se ao invés de colocar `sizeof(int)` colocar o tipo no `sizeof` com base no ponteiro:

```
int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
```

Repare que se quiser trocar o tipo de `ptr` para `char*` toda a instrução continua válida não sendo necessário alterar mais nada, pois neste caso será convertido para `char*`:

```
char *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
```

Para além disto acaba por dar mais legibilidade ao código pois ele é menos extenso, especialmente quando os tipos a serem alocados são longos.

Compare:

```
unsigned long long *ptr = (unsigned long long*) malloc(sizeof(unsigned long long));
```

Com:

```
unsigned long long *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
```

Answer (score 4):

A função malloc retorna um ponteiro para uma memória sem tipo (void*), porém, normalmente vamos usar essa memória com um ponteiro de algum tipo definido e por isso a primeira linha faz o cast para (int*) (o que indica que ptr era do tipo int*). Já a segunda linha ptr é do tipo void* (caso contrário daria erro de compilação).