# Erro na implementação de Pilhas em C

Tags: c

Estou digitando o código que está apresentado em um livro e compilando aos poucos. Os erros acontecem onde estão "//???????????".

Outro detalhe, na declaração da estrutura, onde se vê *Pilha, nessa estrutura, por ser declarada como ponteiro, eu estaria passando o endereço das variáveis dentro da estrutura, correto?

```
#include<stdio.h>        
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef char Itemp;      

typedef struct pilha{   
    int max;   
    int topo;  
    Itemp *item;
    
} *Pilha;   

Pilha pilha(int m){  
    Pilha P=malloc(sizeof(struct pilha));//????????  
    P->max=m;  
    P->topo=-1;
    P->item=malloc(m*sizeof(Itemp));//???????????   
    return P;    
}

int vaziap(Pilha P){        
    if(P->topo==-1) return 1;        
    else return 0;        
}

int cheiap(Pilha P){    
    if(P->topo==P->max-1) return 1;    
    else return 0;   
}

void empilha(Itemp x,Pilha P){         
    if(cheiap(P)) puts("pilha cheia!"); abort();        
    P->topo++;        
    P->item[P->topo]=x;        
    
}
```

Comment: Seria legal informar os erros que aparecem na tela.

Comment: Creio que a variável `P`, do tipo Pliha, deva ser uma variável global e não local à função `pilha`. Estude escopo de variáveis.

Comment: Acho que ao invés de `if(cheiap(P)) puts("pilha cheia!"); abort();`, o que você queria era `if(cheiap(P)) { puts("pilha cheia!"); abort(); }` - O `{` e o `}` são importantíssimos aqui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente isso:

```c
#include<stdio.h>        
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef char Item_Pilha;      

typedef struct Pilha {
    int max;
    int topo;
    Item_Pilha *item;
} Pilha;

Pilha *criar_pilha(int m) {
    Pilha *p = (Pilha *) malloc(sizeof(Pilha));
    p->max = m;
    p->topo = -1;
    p->item = (Item_Pilha *) malloc(m * sizeof(Item_Pilha));
    return p;
}

int pilha_vazia(Pilha *p) {
    return p->topo == -1;
}

int pilha_cheia(Pilha *p) {
    return p->topo == p->max - 1;
}

void empilhar(Item_Pilha x, Pilha *p) {
    if (pilha_cheia(p)) {
        puts("pilha cheia!");
        abort();
    }
    p->topo++;
    p->item[p->topo] = x;
}
```

Enfim, não tente esconder o `*` com um `typedef` porque essa é uma forma bem fácil de fazer besteiras a menos que você saiba muito bem o que você está fazendo e tenha uma razão bem forte para fazer isso.

Além disso, faça de tudo para evitar colisão de nomes, pois no seu exemplo, `pilha` era o nome da `struct`, mas também o da função de criar a pilha, e esse tipo de coisa tende a deixar o compilador confuso, ou ao menos quem for tentar ler o código vai ficar confuso.

E acho que aqueles `{` e `}` no `if` da função de empilhar, você tinha esquecido e com isso, o `abort();` estava fora do `if`, sendo sempre executado.

E dê uma olhada também [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/285379/132).

Comment: Fico grato, se vc ou alguém tiver alguma sugestão de livros sobre estrutura de dados fico grato também!