# Alocação dinâmica de memória dá erro ao acessar

Tags: c, memória

Estou com um problema no meu código:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void a(void *po, size_t t)
{
    void *r = realloc(po, t);
}


int main()
{
    uint8_t *array = NULL;

    a(array, sizeof(uint8_t) * 2);

    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 3;

    return 0;
}
```

Ao tentar inserir dados no array aparecer esse erro:

```
 segmentation fault
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 3):

O primeiro problema é que está realocando o objeto e jogando na variável `r` que morre ali. Parece que quer jogar em `po` mesmo para isso se refletir em `array` na função chamadora.

Mas aí encontramos outro problema, você não quer passar o objeto e sim o ponteiro para o objeto, então deve passar `&array` para pegar um ponteiro para `array`, que por acaso é um ponteiro. E é claro, o parâmetro deve receber um ponteiro para o que vai receber, então deve ser um ponteiro para outro ponteiro. E o tipo correto ali é `uint8_t`.

Corrigindo esses problemas você passar um endereço de memória para uma função, ele será alterado para outro endereço e como foi passando por referência ele é alterado na variável que serviu de argumento, que é o que deseja.

Espero que isso seja só para demonstrar o mecanismo porque em código real não faz muito sentido fazer isto.

Do jeito que estava nada era alterado em `array` que continuava apontando para nulo.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void a(uint8_t **po, size_t t) {
    *po = realloc(*po, t);
}

int main() {
    uint8_t *array = NULL;
    a(&array, sizeof(uint8_t) * 2);
    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 3;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/OiEJjG). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/qifpgkmx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/PassPointerByReference.c).

Comment: acho q essa linha `*po = realloc(*po, t)` pode dar erro de conversão, pode confirmar?

Comment: Que erro pode dar?

Comment: eu tentei aqui https://ideone.com/JiFIpz, aqui http://cpp.sh/ e aqui https://www.mycompiler.io/new/cpp  e dá o erro `invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}' [-fpermissive]`, se testar o código deve conseguir replicar esse erro de compilação

Comment: https://ideone.com/OiEJjG (a questão é sobre C e não C++) https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/285379/101 e https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/221800

Comment: humm já vi qual a diferença Maniero, os dois código estão igual nos 2 links do ideone, mas um foi compilado com "language: C99 (gcc 8.3)", o seu link que funciona, e o outro foi compilado com "language:C++ (gcc 8.3)", parece que não funciona com `c++` ou alguma outra característica do compilador que não sei dizer

Comment: C e C++ são linguagens diferentes, ao contrário da crença popular.

Comment: sim, mesmo num código aparentemente simples fica evidente a diferença +1