# Qual o significado de ”(int*)”

Tags: c

Estava estudando sobre ponteiros e me deparei com o seguinte código:

```
int i;
int *v;
v = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
```

Consigo entender que estou solicitando uma alocação de memória para 10 números inteiros na variável `v`, porém queria saber qual o significado desse `(int*)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc), a função `malloc` retorna um ponteiro do tipo `void*`.

Ponteiros do tipo `void*` são, por definição, “genéricos”, no sentido de que podem apontar para algum valor de tipo estaticamente desconhecido. Como `void*` é intencionalmente genérico, você não sabe, somente pelo tipo, qual é o tipo do valor armazenado naquele endereço. [Veja mais aqui.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/97148/69296)

A função `malloc` pode alocar espaço para qualquer coisa. Ela aloca a memória e não se interessa com o que, de fato, será colocado ali. Por isso retorna `void*`.

Desse modo, quando você faz:

```
int* v = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
```

Ocorre uma *coerção implícita*, do tipo `void*` (retornado por `malloc`) para `int*` (o tipo declarado para a variável `v`).

Em C++, esse tipo de conversão implícita não é permitida. O compilador emite um erro, de modo que você é obrigado a fazer um *cast* explícito:

```
int* v = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
```

<sup>Não tenho como confirmar esta hipótese, mas julgo que, como é “obrigatório” em C++, algumas pessoas trouxeram essa prática de volta para o C, mesmo que não seja necessário.</sup>

É isso que o `(int*)` é: **um *cast***. Ele só faz uma “conversão” explícita.

Esse *cast* não é necessário em C. É opcional, você não precisa fazer porque, como vimos anteriormente, há uma coerção implícita.

Veja que [**há quem advogue contrariamente a essa prática em C**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/7445826).

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/285379/112052

Comment: Talvez seja duplicada, @hkotsubo, eu concordaria com o voto.